# How to post a 2-day recurring event on a Sharepoint calendar?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, recurring-events

This question is more out of curiosity than need, but so far I haven't been able to figure out a solution. We frequently set up recurring events on our intranet calendars, and have promoted the use of Sharepoint calendars over Outlook ones. Today I found out that the Thanksgiving holiday wasn't displaying correctly - we close on Thanksgiving (Thursday) and the day after (Black Friday), but our main company calendar was showing the previous Friday (11/22/19) instead of the correct one (11/29/19).

While correcting this, I found that the Friday event was set to a yearly recurring event - the fourth Friday of November. It was apparently set up like this because there is no duration field on a recurring event. In other words, there is no option below to set the recurring "Thanksgiving" event as a two-day event rather than one day:

[image]

When you uncheck the "All Day Event" option, you can choose a Start Time & End Time, but only within the 24 hours of that single day. The "Date Range" value at the bottom is for the series as a whole, not the event. So basically I'm at a loss here.

**How can you post a 2-day recurring event on a Sharepoint calendar?**

Answer (score 0):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/sharepoint-calendars-i-make-the-most-of-your-team-calendar-RZ010255072.aspx?section=5

You'll add items one at a time by clicking New Item on the New menu. Then you'll enter the item's details in a form. One other thing we should mention: It's easy to create recurring items, such as a weekly staff meeting. You do this by selecting the Make this a repeating event check box and then setting the item's recurrence pattern (for example, for a weekly lunch meeting you would set the pattern to weekly).

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e3b81c14-3217-4450-89ea-627620c126c2/recurring-events-in-calendar-view-of-sharepoint-2010-lists

The Recurrence Data field is unique to the Event Content Type. I don't see any way to add it to an existing list. You would need to recreate your list using Calendar list as the base if you were to use this approach.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/04/11/how-to-make-the-sharepoint-calendar-events-recurring-by-default.aspx